# function expression is evaluated first

Tags: javascript, function, expression

I am new to JavaScript and I am reading a book which says:

> In a function expression e.g. f(0) (where f is the function expression) the function expression is evaluated first. If the value of the function expression is not a callable object, a TypeError is thrown.

What does it mean that

(1) The function expression is evaluated first

(2) The function expression is not a callable object?

My thoughts:

(1): The primitive definition of the function is loaded first

(2): For the example from above (" e.g. f(0) ") this means: There exists no such function f.

Is that right?

Comment: A function expression is not necessarily just a function name, it can be an expression of any complexity. For instance, you can have an array of functions, and then do `array[i](0)`. It will evaluate the expression `array[i]` to get the function.

Comment: Which book is that? `f(0)` is a *CallExpression* where `f` is an *Identifier*. When the expression is evaluated, the value of `f` is looked up in the current environment. Or is `f` a "meta-placeholder" for an arbitrary expression?

Answer (score 0):

> the function expression es evaluated first

This means that the JS engine looks up the value of `f`

> the function expression is not a callable objekt

That means "If `f` is not a function"